# Mac Terminal Command: Move file starting with same name to trash safely

Tags: macos, file, terminal, command

since I will always have multiple Screenshot saved in Desktop.
The usual way I deal with them is:

- in terminal : `trash file`

It is a command I found here: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/trash

while it is slow to move them to trash one by one

Then, I found another way to delete file starting with same name all at once: `find ~/Desktop -type f -name "Screenshot*" -delete`

while it is not safe, since it will nuke all files

I tried to combined them as `find ~/Desktop -type f -name "Screenshot*" -trash`, but failed.

Error msg is: *find: -trash: unknown primary or operator*

Anyone knows how to safely move files starting with the same name to trash all at once in terminal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a simple regular expression will solve your problem:

```
$ ls
Screenshot 2022-07-06 at 12.12.23.png   test2
Screenshot-test             test1                   test3   test4

$ trash ~/Desktop/Screenshot*

$ ls
test1   test2   test3   test4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is simple and clear to follow!